# How to fix the arabic encoding problem in the data transfer from ms-access to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I tried to transfer arabic data from MS-Access to MySQL and display it on php page using datatables API. My code is exactly this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-lb">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<?php
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";

$password = "0000";
$dbname = "mysqlcompdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$query ="SELECT pername,MOBIL_NO,PC_NAME,PC_STYLE,listno,amount,salepric,PC_ITMNO FROM inquiryrep";  
$result = $conn->query($query);
?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>تقرير متابعة الزبائن</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" /> 

           <h1 align="center">تقرير متابعة الزبائن</h1>

      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table id="followup" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >  
                          <thead>  
                               <tr> 
                                    <td>رقم الموبايل</td>                                     
                                    <td>سعر البيع</td>  
                                    <td>العدد</td>  
                                    <td>رقم القائمة</td>  
                                    <td align="right">الموديل</td>  
                                    <td align="right">اسم المادة</td>
                                    <td>رمز المادة</td>
                                    <td align="right">اسم الزبون</td>                                   
                               </tr>  
                          </thead>  
                          <?php  

                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo '  
                               <tr>                                     
                                    <td><a href="tel:'.$row["MOBIL_NO"].'">'.$row["MOBIL_NO"].'</a></td> 
                                    <td>'.number_format($row["salepric"]).'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["amount"].'</td>                                        
                                    <td>'.$row["listno"].'</td>  
                                    <td align="right">'.$row["PC_STYLE"].'</td>                                   
                                    <td align="right">'.$row["PC_NAME"].'</td>                                     
                                    <td>'.$row["PC_ITMNO"].'</td>                                      
                                    <td align="right">'.$row["pername"].'</td>  
                               </tr>  
                               ';  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#followup').DataTable( {
            responsive: true
        } );
 });  
 </script>
```

I got this ÕÇÏÞ ÚÈæÏ ÚíÓì in the fields that have arabic data. All Collation are set to utf8_general_ci, Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8).

I hope all required information available for you guys to help me out solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

i have not more idea but 
confirm both side character set is `utf8_general_ci` (it should be same) if you was change after create table `utf8_general_ci` so not work , recreate mysql tabel